# How to call and pass custom arguments to a python script in sagemaker steps/pipeline?

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I have some processing job that i run as a step in sagemaker pipelines, i pass the my python script filename/path to the script processor and also specify command = ['python3']. my main.py file can take an argument and locally i can call it as such => python3 main.py -f somevalue.

how can i achieve the same thing while running this file via steps in sagemaker pipelines,
i tried this => command = ['python3', "src/main.py" "-f", "somevalue"]. but this doesn't work.

is there anyother way to call my script and pass the arugument ?

main.py

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArugumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f", "--flag", type=boolean) 

is_enabled = args.flag

def main():

if(is_enabled):
  //do something
```

```
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor

my_processor = ScriptProcessor(
    framework_version=framework_version,  # e.g. "1.0-1", 
    role=role, 
    instance_type=your_instance_type,  # e.g. 'ml.m5.large'
    base_job_name = your_base_job_name,
    instance_count=your_instance_count,  # e.g. 1
    command = ['python3']
)

my_step = ProcessingStep(
    code=your_script_path,
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(
            input_name='custom',
            source='src/main.py',
            destination="/opt/ml/processing/input/data",
            s3_data_type='S3Prefix',
            s3_input_mode="File"
        )
    ]
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For sending in additional CLI arguments, you'll want the `arguments` parameter rather than `command` - because all elements of command get positioned [before your script location](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/6384d9509659b35210f7756c7d53b4c8ec9b3ace/src/sagemaker/processing.py#L842), whereas you probably want them after e.g. `python3 your-script.py --flag`

To minimise the code change in your notebooks between experimenting with jobs interactively and connecting them into pipelines, I'd also suggest switching to the newer *pipeline session syntax* as shown in [this example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/train-register-deploy-pipeline-model/train%20register%20and%20deploy%20a%20pipeline%20model.ipynb). The pipeline session allows you to build step definitions with the same function calls as you would usually run jobs (estimator.fit(), processor.run(), etc).

...So instead of:

```py
my_processor = ScriptProcessor(
    command=['python3'],
    ...
)

my_step = ProcessingStep(
    "MyPreprocessStep",
    code=your_script_path,
    inputs=[...],
    arguments=["--flag"],
    ...
)
```

...you could have:

```py
from sagemaker.workflow.pipeline_context import PipelineSession

# Swap this out to run interactively instead of building a pipeline:
session = PipelineSession()

my_processor = ScriptProcessor(
    command=['python3'],
    sagemaker_session=session,
    ...
)

my_step = ProcessingStep(
    "MyPreprocessStep",
    step_args=my_processor.run(
        code=your_script_path,
        inputs=[...],
        arguments=["--flag"],
        ...
    ),
)
```

...Which is closer to the syntax you'd usually use for initially testing your stand-alone job outside of a pipeline (`processor.run()`).